# Pivot wider in BigQuery - create a new column for each row from a separate table

Tags: google-bigquery

```
with
  players as (
    select 11 as playerId, 'Tom' as name union all
    select 12 as playerId, 'Tim' as name union all
    select 13 as playerId, 'Jim' as name union all
    select 14 as playerId, 'Bob' as name union all
    select 15 as playerId, 'Jef' as name union all
    select 16 as playerId, 'Nik' as name union all
    select 17 as playerId, 'Joe' as name union all
    select 18 as playerId, 'Don' as name union all
    select 19 as playerId, 'Jak' as name union all
    select 20 as playerId, 'Bil' as name union all
    select 21 as playerId, 'Rob' as name 
  ),

  game_data as (
    select 3 as points, 11 as h1, 12 as h2, 13 as h3, 17 as a1, 18 as a2, 19 as a3 union all
    select 2 as points, 11 as h1, 12 as h2, 14 as h3, 17 as a1, 18 as a2, 20 as a3 union all
    select 4 as points, 11 as h1, 12 as h2, 16 as h3, 17 as a1, 18 as a2, 22 as a3 union all
    select 1 as points, 13 as h1, 15 as h2, 16 as h3, 19 as a1, 21 as a2, 22 as a3 union all
    select 4 as points, 13 as h1, 15 as h2, 16 as h3, 20 as a1, 21 as a2, 22 as a3
  ),

  output as (
    select 3 as points, 1 as _11, 1 as _12, 1 as _13, 0 as _14, 0 as _15, 0 as _16, -1 as _17, -1 as _18, -1 as _19, 0 as _20, 0 as _21, 0 as _22 union all
    select 2 as points, 1 as _11, 1 as _12, 0 as _13, 1 as _14, 0 as _15, 0 as _16, -1 as _17, -1 as _18, 0 as _19, -1 as _20, 0 as _21, 0 as _22 union all
    select 4 as points, 1 as _11, 1 as _12, 0 as _13, 0 as _14, 0 as _15, 1 as _16, -1 as _17, -1 as _18, 0 as _19, 0 as _20, 0 as _21, -1 as _22 union all
    select 1 as points, 0 as _11, 0 as _12, 1 as _13, 0 as _14, 1 as _15, 1 as _16, 0 as _17, 0 as _18, -1 as _19, 0 as _20, -1 as _21, -1 as _22 union all
    select 4 as points, 0 as _11, 0 as _12, 1 as _13, 0 as _14, 1 as _15, 1 as _16, 0 as _17, 0 as _18, 0 as _19, -1 as _20, -1 as _21, -1 as _22
  )

select * from output
```

There are 12 rows in `players` with the 12 different possible players. `game_data` has rows with points, 3 home playerIds in `h1`, `h2`, and `h3` and 3 away playerIds in `a1`, `a2` and `a3`.

**output**
[image]

We are looking to create a new table `output`, derived from `players` and `game_data`, that has 1 column for each of the 12 playerIds, 1 row for each row in `game_data`, and the values -1, 0, and 1 in the cells:

- -1 if the playerId is the ID in `a1`, `a2`, or `a3` in the row
- +1 if the playerId is the ID in `h1`, `h2`, or `h3` in the row
- 0 if the playerId is not in the row

Since column names cannot be numbers, I've added underscores as prefixes to all of the column names.

Is this possible in BigQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select * except(game_id) from (
  select playerId, format('%t', g) game_id, points, 
    case 
      when playerId in (h1, h2, h3) then 1
      when playerId in (a1, a2, a3) then -1
      else 0
    end category
  from players p, game_data g
)
pivot (any_value(category) for playerId in (11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Let's say we had hundreds of playerIds rather than just 12, and wanted to dynamically set the playerIds. Is this possible? It doesn't seem like we can replace the `(11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21)` vector with a select statement `select distinct playerId from players`, as we get an error `Syntax error: Unexpected keyword SELECT`

Comment: Sure. Can be done with use of EXECUTE IMMEDIATE. Check few of my recent answers to see examples of such